# Use cell reference inside google spreadsheet function

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-apps, google-finance, xml-import

I am using Google Spreadsheet function. 
This formula works fine.

```
=ImportXML("https://www.google.com/finance?q=SHA:000001", "//span[@class='pr']")
```

The string `SHA:000001` is contained in cell `B4`. I would like to use cell reference. So, I changed to formula to

```
=ImportXML("https://www.google.com/finance?q=" + B4, "//span[@class='pr']")
```

Unfortunately, this did not work. The value returned is `#VALUE!`. How should the correct formula look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an ampersand not a plus sign:-

```
=ImportXML("https://www.google.com/finance?q="&B4, "//span[@class='pr']")
```